# How to add user using telegram bot

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I need to add users using a telegram bot, I know that the standard bot API will not be able to do this, what other options can there be?

I read that you can do this through the client, maybe someone has examples of this?

Comment: you can use telethon , but Telegram have limit in Adding members every 5 seconds. maybe block your account


 https://docs.telethon.dev/

Answer (score 0):

**I already develope the code for it
You can access it from the [link](https://github.com/DeAref/TMA)**
(developed with telethon library)